# email attachment with web service in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, web-services, email-attachments

I deployed a web service in a server for sending email and this is the code of it.

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function SendEmailSMTPAtt(ByVal objMail As clsEmail) As String

        Dim strReturn As String = ""
        Dim mailMsg As New MailMessage

        With mailMsg
            .From = objMail.Mailfrom
            .To = objMail.MailTo
            If objMail.Mailcc <> "" Then
                .Cc = objMail.Mailcc
            End If
            If objMail.MailBcc <> "" Then
                .Bcc = objMail.MailBcc
            End If

            .Subject = objMail.MailSubject

            Dim sHtml As String
            sHtml = "<HTML>" & _
             "<HEAD>" & _
             "<TITLE>E-Mail alert </TITLE>" & _
             "</HEAD>" & _
             "<BODY><P>" & _
             "<Font Color=Green>" & objMail.MailBodyText & "</Font>" & _
             "</BODY>" & _
             "</HTML>"

            .Body = sHtml
            .BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html

            Dim attachment1 As New MailAttachment(objMail.strPath) 'objMail.strPath is comming from local machine program Eg: "F:\TestFolder\abc.txt"
            .Attachments.Add(attachment1) 'add the attachment

        End With

        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = EmailService.My.Settings.SMTP_SERVER
        SmtpMail.Send(mailMsg)

        Return strReturn
    End Function
```

This service is working fine except attachment. When send attachment path via my local machine program, it is throw an error "**Server was unable to process request. ---> Invalid mail attachment 'C:\Users*******'**". This error occurred due to web service find that path in the server. But actually path is not exist in the server, because it is a local machine path.

**So how to send local machine attachment via email?**

I just checking out this with internet. But most of the solutions include all code in one program. (send email service part and the client part) But my issue is email service host in a server and I call the method from the local machine.

Comment: The web service can not see files outside of the directory that the web service is running. Try creating a share under the web service or create a virtual directory to use the other share / directory.

Comment: Ohh... is that the only method for achieving this task. So mail services like gmail, yahoo using the same method like this? first copy that file to some share location and pick from it?

Comment: All of those big services have their own custom code. You could try to load the attachment to memory and then send it from the service, that way you would not be directly accessing the disk.